# Logic operators behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning JavaScript (Python background) and I'm having trouble on the logic behind stacking logic operators.

Let me explain.

In Python `(61 <= 81 < 81)` would output `False`. Which makes sense since it's basically `(61 <= 81 AND 81 < 81)`.

But for some reason this same condition `(61 <= 81 < 81)` outputs `True` in JavaScript, almost as if it is reading it as `(61 <= 81 OR 81 < 81)` which is not expected. On the other hand if I explicitly write `(61 <= 81 && 81 < 81)` the output is `False` as expected.

Could anyone explain?

Comment: It works like `a < b && b < c`.  You cannot do `a < b < c` in JavaScript.

Comment: Honestly in this case it's Python that's kind-of weird.

Answer (score 3):

The evaluation of `61 <= 81 < 81`  is not comparing 81.

You have `(61 <= 81)` which is `true` and then it is `true < 81`

The only way to do what you want is to break it up into two checks with an AND

`61 <= 81 && 81 < 81`